# jQuery: very simple tab switching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a very simple tab switching mechanism using jQuery (it's for a WordPress plugin where all tabs show fields that must belong to the same form.)

My goal is:
1) the clicked tab gets highlighted as active;
2) the content referred to the clicked tab gets visible taking the place of the previously displayed content;
3) only the currently active content must be visible and only its tab must be highlighted.

My HTML code is something like this:

```
    <html>
      <body>
      <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        <a href="#tab-1" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active">First</a>
        <a href="#tab-2" class="nav-tab">Second</a>
        <a href="#tab-3" class="nav-tab">Third</a>
      </h2>
      <hr />
      <section id="tab-1" class="tab-content active">
        <P>Some content here.</P>
      </section>
      <section id="tab-2" class="tab-content hidden">
        <p>Some more here.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="tab-3" class="tab-content hidden">
        <p>Something else here.</p>
      </section>
    </body>
  </html>
```

and my **broken** jQuery code is:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $('h2.nav-tab-wrapper > a').click(function(event) {
    // Clicked anchor: prevent browser from taking action.
    event.preventDefault();

    // jQuery selector to display tab content.
    var active_tab_selector = $('h2.nav-tab-wrapper > a').attr('href');

    // Find the activated navigation and remove '.active'.
    var activated_nav = $('h2.nav-tab-wrapper > a.nav-tab-active');
    activated_nav.removeClass('nav-tab-active');

    // Add '.active' to the clicked navigation.
    $(this).parents('a').addClass('nav-tab-active');

    // Hide the displayed tab content.
    $(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active');
    $(active_tab_selector).addClass('hidden');

    // Show target tab content.
    var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hidden');
    $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
  });
})( jQuery );
```

It doesn't work as expected. You can try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alessandro_Maselli/5ftr8jpw/30/) (with some minimum CSS omitted here.)

I'm new to jQuery. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sibling()` selector

```js
$('.nav-tab').click(function(e) {
  //Toggle tab link
  $(this).addClass('nav-tab-active').siblings().removeClass('nav-tab-active');

  //Toggle target tab
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.nav-tab-active {
  color: #f00;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
  <a href="#tab-1" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active">First</a>
  <a href="#tab-2" class="nav-tab">Second</a>
  <a href="#tab-3" class="nav-tab">Third</a>
</h2>
<hr />
<section id="tab-1" class="tab-content active">
  <P>Some content here.</P>
</section>
<section id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
  <p>Some more here.</p>
</section>
<section id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
  <p>Something else here.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you all!
I'm a newbie with jQuery. To a different extent each answer taught me something useful.
This one in particular is smart, simple and definitely solved my problem.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the siblings haha.
Nice one.

Comment: This has a surprisingly low number of upvotes and deserves more.

Answer (score 3):

Several things I would recommend:

1. The `wrapper` should include the tab content panes as well. This way if you have multiple tab containers on the same page, the wrapper knows which tabs and panes belong together.
2. Write jQuery features using a plugin. Defining `$.fn.tabs` allows us to do things like `$(selector).tabs()` instead of putting a big mess of code in our `(function ($) { ... })(jQuery)` on-ready block
3. the `hidden` class is redundant and making your program harder to write. If a tab (or tab content pane) has the `active` class, it is active - otherwise it is *not* active.
4. Because the plugin toggles `active` on all child components in a wrapper, this may cause screen flickering (depending on your CSS) if we click on a tab that is already active. We should prevent the plugin from firing on active tabs.
5. Use event delegation with `.on` to attach an event listener to each *wrapper* instead of using `.click` to attach an event listener to each *tab*. Using more event listeners results in programs that are slower to respond to events. Use as few listeners as possible.
6. It'd be nice if we could customize which tab and content pane is initially active. Perhaps the user clicks `/about#contact-us` and that goes to the *About* page with the *Contact Us* tab active. Unless the HTML has the `active` class set for the *Contact Us* tab, it will not be displayed. This is a more advanced feature, so we cover it in a separate section at the end of this answer.

Here's a full working demo. Adjustments have been made to include recommendations above -

```js
// write new features as a plugin
$.fn.tabs = function () {
  // for each tab wrapper ... 
  return this.each(function () {
    // capture wrapper context
    var wrapper = this
    // use single click event per wrapper, delegate  only to inactive tabs
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.nav-tab:not(.active)', function (event) {
      // remove all active
      $('.active', wrapper).removeClass('active')
      // get the clicked tab
      var clicked = $(event.target)
      // add the active class
      clicked.addClass('active')
      // find the tab's content and add the active class
      $(clicked.attr('href'), wrapper).addClass('active')
    })
  })
};

// keep on-ready function nice and clean!
(function ($) {
  $('.tab-wrapper').tabs()
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.nav-tab.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="#tab-1" class="nav-tab active">First</a>
    <a href="#tab-2" class="nav-tab">Second</a>
    <a href="#tab-3" class="nav-tab">Third</a>
  </nav>
  <hr />
  <section id="tab-1" class="tab-content active">
    <P>Tab Contents 1</P>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    <p>Tab Contents 2</p>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    <p>Tab Contents 3</p>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="tab-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="#tab-1" class="nav-tab active">First</a>
    <a href="#tab-2" class="nav-tab">Second</a>
    <a href="#tab-3" class="nav-tab">Third</a>
  </nav>
  <hr />
  <section id="tab-1" class="tab-content active">
    <P>Some content here.</P>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    <p>Some more here.</p>
  </section>
  <section id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    <p>Something else here.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

---

**How to pass options to plugins** -

As a beginner, it's unlikely you have have written your own jQuery plugin before. As you can see above, there's almost nothing to it. The one piece missing is the ability to send options or *arguments* to the plugin -

```
// make our function accept an argument, userOptions
$.fn.tabs = function (userOptions) {
  // merge default options with userOptions
  var options =
    $.extend(true, $.fn.tabs.defaults, userOptions || {})

  return this.each(function () {
    // capture wrapper context
    var wrapper = this
    // setup event listener (truncated)
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.nav-tab:not(.active)', ...)
    // click the initial tab  
    $(options.initialTab, wrapper).click()
  });
};

// default options
$.fn.tabs.defaults =
  { initialTab: '.nav-tab:eq(0)' };
```

Now if you forget to put `active` class on your tabs or panes, the plugin will still activate the initial tab based on the default selector, the first tab, `.nav-tab:eq(0)`.

To create a tab container with a custom initial tab, we pass an option to our plugin. For example the third tab, `.nav-tab:eq(2)` -

```
$('.tab-wrapper').tabs({ initialTab: '.nav-tab:eq(2)' })
```

Comment: click on `<a>` inside tab content may cause an error

Comment: Aswin, changed `a:not(.active)` to `.nav-tab:not(.active)`. thanks for catching that :D

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ACTIVE from all to set the active on the designed tab.

```js
$('.nav-tab').click(function(e){

var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');

 $('.tab-content').addClass('hidden');
 $('.tab-content').removeClass('active');
    $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hidden');
    $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');

})
```

```css
.active{display:block}
.hidden{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <body>
      <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        <a href="#tab-1" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active">First</a>
        <a href="#tab-2" class="nav-tab">Second</a>
        <a href="#tab-3" class="nav-tab">Third</a>
      </h2>
      <hr />
      <section id="tab-1" class="tab-content active">
        <P>Some content here.</P>
      </section>
      <section id="tab-2" class="tab-content hidden">
        <p>Some more here.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="tab-3" class="tab-content hidden">
        <p>Something else here.</p>
      </section>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of in a hurry now, but the first thing that is missing is to hide all the "active" ones when you click on some tab, add:

```
$('.tab-content').removeClass('active');
```

after your `preventDefault()` and give it a try.