# unload div content of previously tabs when new tab is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

Here is the answer I found [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927659)

However this method just only hide the content not completely unload or remove them.
It's work good if use with text or images, but not with videos and audio, when playing video content of 1st tab then select next tab, video playback still working in background!
My question is: Can I completely remove content from inactive tabs? Thank you!

Here is the code [Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbnyeqdf/)

```js
$('.nav-tab').click(function(e){

var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');

 $('.tab-content').addClass('hidden');
 $('.tab-content').removeClass('active');
    $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hidden');
    $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');

})
```

```css
.active{display:block}
.hidden{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <body>
      <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
        <a href="#tab-1" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active">First</a>
        <a href="#tab-2" class="nav-tab">Second</a>
        <a href="#tab-3" class="nav-tab">Third</a>
      </h2>
      <hr />
      <section id="tab-1" class="tab-content active">
        <P>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8s3bdVxuFBs" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</P>
      </section>
      <section id="tab-2" class="tab-content hidden">
        <p><video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
</video></p>
      </section>
      <section id="tab-3" class="tab-content hidden">
        <p><iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/830279092&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe><div style="font-size: 10px; color: #cccccc;line-break: anywhere;word-break: normal;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis; font-family: Interstate,Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Sans,Garuda,Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif;font-weight: 100;"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/uiceheidd" title="Juice WRLD" target="_blank" style="color: #cccccc; text-decoration: none;">Juice WRLD</a> · <a href="https://soundcloud.com/uiceheidd/tell-me-you-love-me" title="Tell Me U Luv Me (with Trippie Redd)" target="_blank" style="color: #cccccc; text-decoration: none;">Tell Me U Luv Me (with Trippie Redd)</a></div></p>
      </section>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS to `.addClass('hidden')` and `.removeClass('active')`, you should remove the element from the DOM completely using the jquery `remove` or standard `removeChild` method:

- jquery remove: https://api.jquery.com/remove/
- HTML DOM remove child: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp